# jqGrid altRows doesn't get applied at all even when I eliminate background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

such a simple project and such a mysterious issue. I added all the libraries and files in the jqGrid documentation in my index.html like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css"/>

<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jqGrid/src/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, I added tables with various id's in the html body:

```
<body>
   <table id="list2"></table>
   <table id="list3"></table>
   <table id="list4"></table>
</body>
```

Last but not least, I added the table id with local data in js:

```
    $("#list3").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Fecha/Hora', 'Acceso', 'Resultado', 'Detalle Tipo Evento', 'APN', 'RNC(3G)/BSC(2G)', 'LAC', 'Celda', 'Vel. Max. Descarga', 'Vel. Max. Subida', 'Dispositivo'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'Fecha/Hora',index:'Fecha/Hora', width:200},
        {name:'Acceso',index:'Acceso', width:200},
        {name:'Resultado', index:'Resultado', width: 150},
        {name:'Detalle Tipo Evento', index:'Detalle Tipo Evento', width: 100},
        {name:'APN', index:'APN', width: 100},
        {name:'RNC(3G)/BSC(2G)', index:'RNC(3G)/BSC(2G)', width: 100},
        {name:'LAC', index:'LAC', width: 100},
        {name:'Celda', index:'Celda', width: 100},
        {name:'Vel. Max. Descarga', index:'Vel. Max. Descarga', width: 100},
        {name:'Vel. Max. Subida', index:'Vel. Max. Subida', width: 100},
        {name:'Dispositivo', index: 'Dispositivo', width: 120}
    ],
    autowidth: false,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'altRowsClass'
});
```

... and updated my styles.css file to contain the class I pointed to in js:

```
.altRowsClass {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #007fff;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

I read the other questions about the table object property named altRow and about ui-lightness theme (how the default altClass theme is not visible). Tried with ui-darkness and no effect (all rows become black). I looked on all the forums, all the questions and still can't figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: If you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) this options is removed and is no more valid. [See here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/about/release-notes/). You can use the style definitions for this purpose

Comment: @TonyTomov, it all makes sense now. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **more deep** CSS selector to be able to overwrite CSS rule defines in jQuery UI CSS. Instead of `.altRowsClass {...}` rule you should use `.ui-jqgrid-btable .altRowsClass {...}` or for example

```css
.ui-jqgrid-btable > tbody > .altRowsClass {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #007fff;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: I just tried to implement this solution or something in the lines of making the selector more specific than this, but it didn't work either. Apparently, the issue with jqGrid is that if you use Gurrido jqGrid, it removes the altRows: true option altogether.

Comment: @IuliaMihet: You should write the correct name of the product, which you use. "jqGrid" exists only till the version 4.7. After that Tony made the product **commertial** (see the price and new license agreement [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) renamed the product to "Guriddo jqGrid JS" (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). At the same time I started *alternative fork* under the name ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which can be used under MIT and GPL v2 licenses completely free of charge. "Free jqGrid" try to hold max compatibility to old jqGrid

Comment: I honestly had no clue there are 2 different jqGrid libraries at this point. Sorry for the confusion.